# Translate recursive Sql-query for Oracle to PostgreSQL (nvl, CONNECT BY PRIOR, START WITH, ORDER SIBLINGS BY)

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have the following query which works for Oracle and returns tree nodes depending on the input `:NodeId` and `:Lvl` parameters:

```
SELECT Id AS TreeId, Parent AS ParentId, MY_ID AS EntityId, name as Name
FROM (SELECT *  FROM TABLE(test_tbl.struct_filter(
             :ObjectTypeId
             ,:FilterTypeId
             ,NULL --p_filter
             ,'adm' --p_user
)))
WHERE level = nvl(:Lvl, level) 
connect by prior id=parent start with id=:NodeId
ORDER SIBLINGS BY order_by_struct(name, my_type)
```

I have some unsorted [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFXMQ.png) in which data can be used to build a tree from nodes, each node has `TreeId` and `ParentId`. If `ParentId = null`, then this is the `root` of the tree. Some other elements have `parentId = root`, so I was able to select a tree node to get its children. To do this, a hierarchical query is used to get all branches, specifying the `NodeId` as the target node for the search. And at the end the received branches are sorted by name

And I'm stuck to write it down so it works the same for PostgreSQL:

```
WITH recursive tmp AS(
    select Id AS TreeId, Parent AS ParentId, MY_ID AS EntityId, name as Name
    FROM test_tbl.struct_filter(
             :ObjectTypeId
             ,:FilterTypeId
             ,NULL
             ,'adm'
             )
    where level = coalesce(:Lvl, level)
    union all
select d.Id AS TreeId, d.Parent AS ParentId, d.MY_ID AS EntityId, d.name as Name
FROM test_tbl.struct_filter(
             :ObjectTypeId
             ,:FilterTypeId
             ,NULL
             ,'adm'
             )
    d
JOIN tmp ON tmp.id = :NodeId )
SELECT Id AS TreeId, Parent AS ParentId, MY_ID AS EntityId, name as Name FROM tmp
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/sql/example/5603/oracle-connect-by-functionality-with-recursive-ctes
example of converting CONNECT BY to CTE.